# In several places, there is an instruction to "spin up a real AWX server". What does that mean?

Tags: installation, ansible

In [the "official" documentation](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/INSTALL.md#building-the-cli-documentation), and elsewhere on the internet, there is an instruction to "spin up an AWX server", or "Spin up a real AWX server", with no explanation of how to actually go about doing that.  This is a prerequisite for installing sphinx, but it isn't clear why this is so.

Note: this is an AWX server, a.k.a. a tower, *not* the service that Amazon provides.  This distinction confuses the search engines.

Comment: _This is a prerequisite for installing sphinx_ > from where are you taking this information? I have seen sphinx running on multiple project to create documentation from reStructuredText documents without the need of an AWX or Tower server. The requirement described there is only if you want to build the docs of AWX/Tower itself, is that what you want to do? If so, this is described in the chapter _"The AWX Operator"_ of the exact same documentation page.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I might even have a locally running sphinx server, as I have a RST live preview plugin installed on my VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

The best and "full" instructions are on the project's [GitHub page](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/INSTALL.md). The application builds the Operator, and installs into into your cluster. If you want to play around with it before installing it "fully" you can use this [documentation](https://github.com/ansible/awx-operator#creating-a-minikube-cluster-for-testing) on how to test the AWX Operator.

From my personal experience, it's a very challenging piece of software to use and run, and if you're looking to use it in a "production" environment, there's a real chance you'll just want to buy the Tower license down the line. The care and feeding of AWX is a full-time job.